# req.body.data got undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My client side

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000/scrape",
      {
      data: 'something'
      },
      function(data, status){
      console.log(data);
      });
```

What I do in node.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/scrape', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.data)

});
```

But I got undefined in console.log(req.body.data), any idea why?

Comment: who downvoted this? at least give a reason

Answer (score 1):

Your data must be of json format. since you are using `bodyParser.json()`.

Try setting the http header, `Content-type` as `application/json` in your `$.post` call and send a valid json structure as data

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "scrape", 
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ someData : "someData}),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
          console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(){
          console.log('error in sending request')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(req.body.data)
```

returns undefined because the data is in `req.body` you should `console.log(req.body)` 
and add `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));` so that data not in json format can also be parsed.

if you want `req.body.data` have data then make request like

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000/scrape",
      {
      data: {data: 'something'}
      },
      function(data, status){
      console.log(data);
      });
```

also your request is not sending any response you need to do something like

```
app.post('/scrape', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.data)
    res.status(200).json({data: reqr.body.data});

});
```

hope it helps :)